# Not able to send parameters from html to controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="AppE" method="post" action="http://10.18.9.10:8280/Ey/lin">
        <input type="text" name="userIdd" id="userIdd"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="passwordd" id="passwordd"><br/>
        <input type="text" name="appSerialNon" id="appSerialNon"><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

/lin goes to this controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@RequestParam(required=false, value="userIdd")String userIdd, @RequestParam(required=false, value="passwordd")String passwordd,@RequestParam(required=false, value="appSerialNon")String appSerialNon ) {
    System.out.println(userIdd+" "+passwordd+" "+appSerialNon); 
    return "login/login"
}
```

After visiting the html and filling values and submit i am redirected to the desired page but i am getting null values on console i.e. i am not able to send parameters from html to controller class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `login()` method responds to HTTP GET requests, but the form sends an HTTP POST.

Use `RequestMethod.POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is sending a post request

`<form name="AppE" method="post" action="http://10.18.9.10:8280/Ey/lin">`

So make your controller accept `POST` requests , change `method = RequestMethod.GET` to `method = RequestMethod.POST`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@RequestParam(required=false, value="userIdd")String userIdd, @RequestParam(required=false, value="passwordd")String passwordd,@RequestParam(required=false, value="appSerialNon")String appSerialNon ) {
    System.out.println(userIdd+" "+passwordd+" "+appSerialNon); 
    return "login/login"
}
```